# Merge indexes option when using more than one OrderBy in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We have more than one OrderBy sortings for a query in Firestore. 
Is there a way to take advantage of [Index merging provided by firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#taking_advantage_of_index_merging) so that we don't need to create composite index for every combination?

Ex : We use search and CreatedAt query params where search is a text search which needs a default orderBy (as we use where operator) and CreatedAt needs another OrderBy. These two needs to be applied for every query.  There are 5 more equality operator checks which are optional.

Problem is that it ends up with many composite index entries as there will be lots of combinations if we can't make use of index merging.

We tried but unable to achieve this. Any inputs to solve this will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple orderBy fields, it's not possible.  The merging you're talking about only works for multiple equality filters.  You will have to create a new index for each case, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh! So i end up here with >5! (factorial) composite indexes. Right?

Comment: I don't know exactly how many you'll really need, but it sounds like, for your particular schema, you will end up creating a lot of them.

Comment: I ended up creating 139 indexes "manually" (through firebase indexes json file) with the optimised combinations. It's unfortunate that composite indexes are such a pain with firestore. Anyways thanks Doug for confirming :)